# HTML5 Videos in Mobile Safari Issue

Tags: html, mobile-safari, html5-video

Here is my scenario:

I am building a "kiosk" application in safari with 2 videos, one acting as a "screensaver" and the other is a supplementary video. The SS is looping fine via: *(done on body onload="init()")*

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('screensaver');
myVideo.addEventListener('ended', playVideo, false);
function playVideo(){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById('screensaver');
  myVideo.play();
}
```

When the user taps the screen during the SS, it fades out `$('#screensaver').fadeOut(1000);` and the user is presented a question with a button to play the next video.

When the second video is done via:

```
$('#presentation').bind('ended', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#swapVideo').show(); //Overlay for user interaction
            $('#screensaver').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#screensaver').get(0).play();
        }); 
    });
```

The SS shows up, plays, but no longer loops. Are eventListeners lost when the display is set to none?

The same thing happens when I try to play the second video again. The 'ended' eventListener seems to be lost...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that iOS ignores `.play()`. Apple believes it's best to prevent sites from automatically playing content, which could potentially eat up someone's data plan or create undesirable actions on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, .play() can only executed directly from a user interaction.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

As for your question, event listeners are not unbound if you change the display property.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpark1120/tcskczvt/2/)

```
$('.container').on('custom', function (evt) {
  $(this).toggle();  
});
```